# Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `Int'

Tags: haskell, ghc, gtk2hs

I have a strange error with Haskell and Gtk2Hs.

I try to set the cursor position in a text entry with

```
set entree [entryCursorPosition := 5 ]
```

which correspond to the Type

```
entryCursorPosition :: EntryClass self => ReadAttr self Int
```

and I have the following error :

```
Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `Int'
```

Do you think it's a bug ? Do you know how to solve it?

I'm using Gtk2Hs 0.12.3 on my Debian Wheezy with GHC 7.4.1.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake `entryCursorPosition` is a **read only** attribut and can't be set.

The correct function to set the cursor position in a entry is :

```
editableSetPosition entry (-1)
```

Hoping it will be helpfull

Answer (score 6):

As you state yourself, `entryCursorPosition` is a `ReadAttr`, which means it cannot be written. Internally,

```
type ReadAttr o a = ReadWriteAttr o a ()
```

So a `ReadAttr` is implemented as an attribute that has "read type" `a`, and "write type" `()`. This explains the error message you see, because you try to set it to an `Int` instead of a `()`.